# Add count column to a existing Select Query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 SELECT queries one which retrieve a team and one which count how many players there are in that team. How can i add that count query in to the first data select query? i've tried by union, but does not work since they do not have the same number of columns.

```
SELECT Subteams.id, Teams.name, Games.name as 'game' 
FROM Subteams, Games, Teams 
WHERE Subteams.gameId = Games.id 
    AND Subteams.teamId = Teams.id


SELECT COUNT(Players.subTeamId) as 'count' 
FROM Subteams, Games, Teams, Players 
WHERE Subteams.gameId = Games.id 
    AND Subteams.teamId = Teams.id 
    AND Players.subTeamId = Subteams.id 
ORDER BY Players.id
```

Comment: Format your queries and write them using proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Peter, learn to write your queries using JOIN instead of WHERE.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `GROUP BY` in the second query? And what's the point of `ORDER BY Players.id` when you're not displaying per-player data?

Comment: oh yes but then it delete the count if it is equal to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the columns from the other tables to the `COUNT()` query.

```
SELECT Subteams.id, Teams.name, Games.name as game, COUNT(Players.subTeamId) as 'count' 
FROM Subteams
JOIN Games ON Subteams.gameId = Games.id
JOIN Teams ON Subteams.teamId = Teams.id
LEFT JOIN Players ON Players.subTeamId = Subteams.id 
GROUP BY Subteams.id
ORDER BY Subteams.id
```

I've also used `LEFT JOIN` so you'll get `0` for teams with no players.